# Method action event is already defined in JavaCal in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-12

I was trying to make a calculator with java in NetBeans follow ing this tutorial here is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZW4ktG1DEE&list=PLAL-dvEAuBBTkYoPZ4XRU3FsoB8Nm03hy

also, this is my code

https://pastebin.com/frvmHM0Y

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        enable(); //call enable
}                                             

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "1");
}                                        
    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "1");
private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText() + "2");
}
```

As I am very new to java and this is my first project so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
extremepro999
aka
extremenoob999

Comment: 1. You didn't say what your problem is. What is the question here. 2. A question should contain all relevant information, including code, in itself. Without need to visit other sites like YT or pastebin.

Comment: the code is too much so i can't paste it here so you will have to see pastebin

Comment: If it is too much then noone will bother to look through it anyway. You should post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all who answered but i found the answer to the error it was a button which had some names.

thanks